# Cannot contact docker container on Windows host

Tags: docker, networking, windows-10, tcp

tl;dr summary of the problem:

- Application launches successfully within container, binds to 127.0.0.1:8080 within the container, and successfully services web requests, but only within the container
- docker ps -a confirms that port 8080 is being exposed
- I cannot communicate with the application from the host using the container's actual IP address when I request http://[Container IP address]:8080
- The host is running Windows 10
- The Windows Firewall is completely disabled for troubleshooting

To troubleshoot I have created the simplest possible application to run in a dockers container, an F# / Suave application like so:

```
open Suave
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =

    startWebServer defaultConfig (Successful.OK "Hello World!")
    0
```

Which works fine, returning a simple "Hello World!" when I run it locally.

To containerize the app I have followed the instructions at "[Dockerize a .NET Core application](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/)" which instructs me to run the container like

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp aspnetapp
```

I cannot connect to the "website" at http://localhost:80 nor http://localhost:8080, which apparently is a common problems for Docker users running Windows.  **However the solution that seems to have fixed this problem for every other Windows user on the internet, running**

```
docker inspect myapp
```

**and then hitting the resulting IPAddress, does not work either.**  I get:

[image]

Hitting both http://172.17.0.2:80 and http://172.17.0.2:8080 in Chrome gives me "Site can't be reached."

Also worth noting, when I run

```
docker logs myapp
```

The only line is

```
[17:43:21 INF] Smooth! Suave listener started in 73.476ms with binding 127.0.0.1:8080
```

As a guess, I have also tried

```
ipconfig
```

[image]

and then hitting the IP address of the Docker NAT adapter, but this also results in an unreachable site.

**UPDATE**:

Another observation which might or might not be relevant:  Many online tutorials suggest that under Windows you need to directly connect to the IP Address of the container, and to get that IP address by running

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" myapp
```

which for me, always yields:

When I run a vanilla

docker inspect myapp

the resulting JSON is not structured exactly like the recommended query.  I get a **bridge** node, but no **nat** node:

[image]

Comment: Do you have firewall enabled on your host machine?

Comment: I disabled it completely in response to your prompting, but still cannot access the application within the container from outside the container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My containerized app needed to listen/bind to 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your app says it’s bound to localhost:8080, but you’re publishing port 80. Stop the container, and rerun with:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name myapp aspnetapp
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  I deleted my container and reran it with your instruction here, and still cannot access the site at localhost:80 nor :8080, nor at the `docker inspect`-reported IP address at either port, or at the `ipconfig`-reported IP address at either port.  Also, `docker logs myapp` still shows the app is launching fine and binding to port 8080 within the container.

Comment: Well, you don’t need to publish port 80. Your application isn’t listening on that port. Exposing 8080 is the right configuration, and further errors should be logged by the application.

Comment: If I'm doing something wrong with the docker configuration, the application won't know that anything is wrong to log.

Comment: I’m saying, once you change your configuration to 8080:8080 as above, there’s nothing else you need to do on docker. You’ve exposed the port that your application is claiming to listen on. Why isn’t it listening on that port, or unable to service requests? That’s something only your application can trace.

Comment: I can connect a new bash session in the container and the app appears to be servicing requests just fine, as well (`curl localhost:8080`), so the app appears to be servicing requests just fine *and* docker seems to be configured to expose the relevant port.  I'm going to research @pankaj-kapare 's firewall suggestion, above.

Comment: Try adding 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80
EXPOSE 80 
in docker file and try re-run the docker container. [Reference](https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2017/02/20/hosting-asp-net-core-docker/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines in docker file

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80 
EXPOSE 80
```

Reference: https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2017/02/20/hosting-asp-net-core-docker/

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the problem.  I shelled into the container and ran `printenv` to ensure that the changes were in effect.